# How do I find out why cron is not running my jobs?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and the cron daemon is running:

```
# ps ax | grep cron
822 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
```

but it is not executing any jobs. I was previously getting entries in `/var/log/syslog` such as this:

```
2014-05-04T11:47:01.839754+01:00 localhost CRON[29253]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly ))
```

but now there are no cron-related entries. I was also getting entries like this in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
2014-05-04T11:47:01.839183+01:00 localhost CRON[29252]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
2014-05-04T11:47:13.495691+01:00 localhost CRON[29252]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

but again, now there are no cron-related entries.

I am not aware that anything has changed. I have tried restarting cron:

```
# service cron restart
cron stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 24907
```

I tried using `crontab -e` to add a cron job `* * * * * date >> /tmp/somefile` which worked, but it installed a new crontab in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`, whereas I want cron to use the file in `/etc/crontab`.

Is there any debug option I can use, or a log somewhere that might give an error message that I can investigate?

Comment: What displayed to crontab -l?

Comment: `no crontab for root`.

Comment: I believe if you do just a little bit of searching on this SE site you'll have an answer.  This is a fairly common problem.

Comment: Crons retrieved using the `crontab` command (`-l` switch) are user-dependent, while `/etc/crontab` is used to store system-wide crons. For this reason, tasks saved in `/etc/crontab` will not appear in anyone's `crontab -l`.

Comment: Note that [Server Fault has a canonical question about cronjob debugging](https://serverfault.com/q/449651/313521) that may help.

Answer (score 4):

To further help you debug what is wrong with your `cron` jobs, you should check your mail. This is usually stored in a file like `/var/mail/<user_name>` or `/var/spool/mail/<user_name>`.

These two files are actually hardlinks on my Debian box, but I don't know if this is standard.

**Explanation**

From the `cron(8)` page:

> When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of  the
>          crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the
>          crontab, if such exists).

Comment: I have checked mail; none is being generated, nor is there a dead.letter file.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that there is no crontab for root, do any users have a crontab entry?  If you are only using root then you could also check the following directories: /etc/cron.daily/ - /etc/cron.hourly/ - /etc/cron.monthly/ - /etc/cron.weekly

on my machine (centos 6.4) i have mlocate.cron inside of the /etc/cron.daily/ directory and cron runs that script daily.

so I think you just need to add cron jobs.

Comment: But there is a crontab file in `/etc/crontab`. Maybe the question is why does `crontab -l` not acknowledge it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the permissions on `/etc/crontab` to the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 778 May 10 21:31 /etc/crontab
```

Previously it was `-rw-rw-r--`. That was the only change. It wasn't working, now it is. Still not sure why.

Comment: The root crontab would execute any commands as root.  Permissions allowing write access to non-root would be considered a security hole.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: But the group write bit would only have given write access to those in the root group - which is presumably just root user(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar type of problem, but after specifying the root as user on the `/etc/crontab`, the cron job started triggering.

It might be due to the syntax followed on the `crontab -e` which is different from the `/etc/crontab`.